# How to I set the value of http headers in a mule FunctionalTestCase

Tags: mule

I have a flow that need to access to a specific header 'REMOTE_USER' from the HTTP request:

```
 <flow name="http" >
      <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="127.0.0.1" port="8501"/>
      <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.get('http.headers').get('REMOTE_USER')]" level="ERROR" />
...
```

I would like to write a unit test with that set this header and test the flow.

```
@Test
public void testSend() throws Exception{
  MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();                                
  HashMap<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  headers.put("REMOTE_USER", "test");
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();           
  properties.put("http.headers", headers);          
  MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:8501", "test", properties);         
  assertNotNull(result.getPayloadAsString());
}
```

Is there a way to test this?

Comment: What you're doing should work: what's the issue? Also note that you may want to use a non-Mule HTTP client (like Apache's) if you want your tests to be Mule-neutral (ie to be sure it will work for all callers).

Comment: With an httpclient it is working. With the help of the debugger, I find out that in fact you don't need to set an http.headers but you must directly put  properties.put("REMOTE_USER", headers);

Comment: Right, stupid me :( `http.headers` is created by Mule. Sorry, I commented too fast.

Answer (score 0):

To add in HTTP header use message-properties with scope outbound:

```
 <message-properties-transformer  doc:name="REMOTE_USER">
            <add-message-property key="REMOTE_USER" value="abcdxyz"/>
 </message-properties-transformer>
```

To test in Functional Test:

```
public class XYZTest extends FunctionalTestCase {

 @Test
 public void testXyz(){
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
        post.set.....
         .......

      org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = hc.execute(post);
      assertNotNull(response.getFirstHeader("REMOTE_USER"));
  }  
}
```

Comment: I wanted to be able to create a unit test where the unit test set the header so i can test my integration/mediation scenario. I did find the answer later and put it in the comment.